# CURL -d equivalent in C

Tags: c, curl

I am looking for an equivalent to the -d option from the command line curl in C.

I want to rewrite this:

`curl -d loginid="test" -d password="test" -d action="Login" somewebpage`

I cannot figure out the C functions which are needed for this.

I'm actually doing it like this:

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "webpage.com");
curl_easy_setopt(curl,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,login_data);

res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
```

login_data looks like this:

```
snprintf(login_data,100,"loginID=%s&password=%s",username,password);
```

I hope you can help

greetings and thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you run your curl command with `--libcurl` and a filename it will save the C code for the command using libcurl in the file.

```
curl --libcurl myprog.c -d loginid="test" -d password="test" -d action="Login" somewebpage
```

Then look in myprog.c:

```
/********* Sample code generated by the curl command line tool **********
 * All curl_easy_setopt() options are documented at:
 * http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_setopt.html
 ************************************************************************/
#include <curl/curl.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  CURLcode ret;
  CURL *hnd;

  hnd = curl_easy_init();
  curl_easy_setopt(hnd, CURLOPT_URL, "somewebpage");
  curl_easy_setopt(hnd, CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS, 1L);
  curl_easy_setopt(hnd, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "loginid=test&password=test&action=Login");
  curl_easy_setopt(hnd, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDSIZE_LARGE, (curl_off_t)39);
  curl_easy_setopt(hnd, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "curl/7.45.0");
  curl_easy_setopt(hnd, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 50L);
  curl_easy_setopt(hnd, CURLOPT_TCP_KEEPALIVE, 1L);

  /* Here is a list of options the curl code used that cannot get generated
     as source easily. You may select to either not use them or implement
     them yourself.

  CURLOPT_WRITEDATA set to a objectpointer
  CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION set to a functionpointer
  CURLOPT_READDATA set to a objectpointer
  CURLOPT_READFUNCTION set to a functionpointer
  CURLOPT_SEEKDATA set to a objectpointer
  CURLOPT_SEEKFUNCTION set to a functionpointer
  CURLOPT_ERRORBUFFER set to a objectpointer
  CURLOPT_STDERR set to a objectpointer
  CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION set to a functionpointer
  CURLOPT_HEADERDATA set to a objectpointer

  */

  ret = curl_easy_perform(hnd);

  curl_easy_cleanup(hnd);
  hnd = NULL;

  return (int)ret;
}
/**** End of sample code ****/
```